# Посмотреть данные из базы и вытащить их в другой класс в Sugar ORM

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sugarorm

Я хочу сделать аутентификацию и регистрацию. Для каждого отдельный класс Activity. Я делаю регистрацию тут:

```
package com.example.dbapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Activity_Registration extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button backToInReg,register;
    EditText name,surname,login,password,age;
    Book book;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.registration);

        backToInReg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backToInReg);
        backToInReg.setOnClickListener(this);

        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        register.setOnClickListener(this);

        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        surname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.surname);
        login = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.login);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String NAME= new String(),SURNAME=new String(),PASSWORD=new String(),LOGIN=new String();
        int AGE;
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.backToInReg:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Registration.this, MainActivity.class);
                MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();

                **ma.mainBook(book);**

                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.register:
                MainActivity mas = new MainActivity();
                NAME = name.getText().toString();
                SURNAME = surname.getText().toString();
                PASSWORD = password.getText().toString();
                AGE = Integer.parseInt(password.getText().toString());
                LOGIN=  login.getText().toString();
                book = new Book(LOGIN,PASSWORD,NAME,SURNAME,AGE);
                **mas.mainBook(book);**
                mas.book =book;
                Toast.makeText(this,"Ok, you succesfull registered!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

А тут аутентификацию:

```
package com.example.dbapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    Button btnAdd, btnRead, btnClear;
    Button backToInReg,register;
    EditText etName, etEmail;
    String login,password;
    Book book;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        register.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    public void mainBook (Book books){
            Log.d("Login ",books.login);
        Log.d("Password ",books.password);
            this.book=books;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnAdd:
                if(tryIt(etName.getText().toString(),  etEmail.getText().toString()) == 1){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"OK!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setContentView(R.layout.second);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Error"+etName.getText().toString()+etEmail.getText().toString()+" - " +book.login+book.password,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                break;
            case R.id.register:

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_Registration.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
    public int tryIt(String login,String password){
        int d=0;
        if(login.equals(book.login)&& password.equals(book.password)){
            d=1;
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

Когда я делаю регистрацию - данные сохраняются. Потом передаю их в класс `MainActivity`, но они не передаются (жирный шрифтом).

Вопрос: как  перемещать базу данных с одного класса в другой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Во первых**, вы нигде не сохраняете ничего в базу. Чтобы сохранить данные в SugarORM нужно вызвать метод `book.save()`.

**Во вторых**, передавать базу никуда не нужно. Она живёт отдельно от ваших классов активити. То есть сохранив запись в одном активити в бд, вы можете получить её в другом, например по `id`, который и нужно передавать между активити.

**В третьих**, чтобы что-то передать между активити, нужно положить это в интент. А то, как делаете это вы

```
MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
ma.mainBook(book);
```

естественно не будет работать. Да, вы создаёте объект и кладёте туда данные, но он нигде и никогда не будет использоваться. Когда вы вызыывете `startActivity`, система сама создаёт объект активити и далее используется именно он.

Итого, что нужно делать:

1) После заполнения данных, сохраняйте объект в бд `book.save();`

2) `book.save()` возвращает `id` созданной записи. Сохраните его в переменную и потом передавайте в интенте при старте новой активити:

```
long id = book.save();
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Registration.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("id", id);
startActivity(intent);
```

3) В новой активити доставайте `id` из интента и берите объект из бд по этому `id`:

```
long id = getIntent().getLongExtra("id", 1);
Book book = Book.findById(Book.class, id);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогло!

Comment: А еще вопрос: Я правильно проверяю логин и пароль с базы данных?

Comment: Что значит правильно? Строки да, нужно сравнивать через `equals()`, если вы об этом.

Comment: Нет, когда я буду проверять, она будет искать по всем данным? 
 public int tryIt(String login,String password){
        int d=0;
        long id = getIntent().getLongExtra("id",1);
        book = Book.findById(Book.class, id);
        if(login.equals(book.login)&& password.equals(book.password)){
            d=1;
        }
        return d;
    }

Comment: Нет конечно. Только по той записи, которую вы вытащили по id. Чтобы искать по всем, нужно `List<Book> books = Book.listAll(Book.class);` и потом в цикле сравнивать с каждой.